# Why SQL Server's MERGE has such a huge Excessive grant when compared to INSERT + DELETE?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance, sql-server-2017, merge

I am trying to optimize a security computation process for a Web application by trying to making it synchronous (compute on the fly for an entity) instead of asynchronous (large computation for all entities once in a while).

I have broken down the business rules and the final step is to update the security information (INSERT, DELETE several dozens/hundreds records in a table that contains several million rows). The table definition is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComputedSecurityContract](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContractId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ComputedSecurityContract] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My first trial involves a MERGE that seems to take more than 95% of the whole stuff the stored procedure is doing:

```
MERGE vComputedSecurityContract AS TARGET
USING #tmpContractSecurity AS SOURCE
    ON (TARGET.UserId = SOURCE.UserId AND TARGET.ContractId = SOURCE.ContractId)
-- when matched there is nothing to be done
--When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT (ContractId, UserId) VALUES (SOURCE.ContractId, SOURCE.UserId)
--When there is a row that exists in target and same record does not exist in source then delete this record target
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    AND (@UserId IS NULL OR TARGET.UserId = @UserId)
    AND (@ContractId IS NULL OR TARGET.ContractId = @ContractId)
THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, 
    DELETED.ContractId AS DeletedContractId, DELETED.UserId AS DeletedUserId, 
    INSERTED.ContractId AS InsertedContractId, INSERTED.UserId AS InsertedUserId;
```

Looking at [the query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByinLX9pD), what struck me is the huge Excessive Grant (360MB, used some KB or 0 if no actual changes are to be made).

My [second attempt](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkR5Dmq6v) is to break the MERGE into separate INSERT + DELETE statements and the relative cost of these queries is way less than that of the MERGE:

```
INSERT INTO vComputedSecurityContract (ContractId, UserId)
OUTPUT 'Inserted' AS Inserted, inserted.ContractId, inserted.UserId
SELECT T.ContractId, T.UserId
FROM #tmpContractSecurity T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vComputedSecurityContract V where V.ContractId = T.ContractId AND V.UserId = T.UserId)

DELETE V
OUTPUT 'Deleted' AS Deleted, deleted.ContractId, deleted.UserId
FROM vComputedSecurityContract V
WHERE (@UserId IS NULL OR V.UserId = @UserId)
    AND (@ContractId IS NULL OR V.ContractId = @ContractId)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmpContractSecurity T where T.ContractId = V.ContractId and T.UserId = V.UserId)
```

I assume that the huge Excessive grant of the MERGE has something to do with this. Why these almost identical operations have such different performance results?

Note: @ContractId and @UserId are stored procedure input parameters.

Comment: Please check this link --> https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/performance-of-the-sql-merge-vs-insertupdate

Comment: Also, obligatory: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: The MemoryGrantWarning is in KB.  The warning is "The query memory grant detected "Excessive Grant", which may impact the reliability. Grant size: Initial 363296 KB, Final 363296 KB, Used 0 KB."

Comment: What happens if you make two separate `MERGE` statements, one where @userId and @contractId are both null, and the other where they are not with the check on those variables in the `NOT MATCHED` clause

Comment: @Charlieface Forgot to mention. Those two are never both null. Current goal for this computation is to apply to a certain entity (contract in this case) and all users OR a certain user and all entities.

Comment: @JustinCave As David Browne said the Grant is expressed in KB (this is clearly shown at the end of the warning at the bottom of the first elements tooltip).

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I am glad that the INSERT + DELETE works better because MERGE is quite cumbersome and things are more clear when they are separated.